# Javascript popup over all applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.NET page, running in IE, that monitors several server jobs running at night. When an error occurs on a job, I have a popup window that opens with javascript, window.open(). The problem is, employees tend to have other applications, such as Netflix, running full screen and do not see the popup window notifying them of the error. I have javascript code on the popup page to continually set focus to itself, so it will blink in the taskbar, but Netflix covers the taskbar, so not helpful.

Currently using:
setInterval('window.focus()',500);

Is there a way to make a popup window in IE that will open over every other application?

Comment: By default, you can't.  This is because javascript is 'sandboxed', meaning it is contained within the browser.  Maybe a solution would be to text / email them alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to overcome to other windows is using `fullscreen=yes` to make your window full screen. It's supported in IE only ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and Mozilla people [hate it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#Note_on_fullscreen)!

Otherwise **you don't have access to OS level from the browser**.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, you only have control over the browser and that is even limited, not the entire Desktop/Laptop.